# Groovy: Confusion about Map Reassign via `getOrDefault`

Tags: groovy

I'm going to initialize a empty Map dynamically in a loop, i.e. `key1` and `key2` are variables in the loop:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List>> map = [
    key1: [
        key2: []
    ]
]
```

I'm trying initialize the map structure by `getOrDefault` in two ways. One (`y`) using the hardcode as key name, another (`x`) using the variable as the keyname:

```
Map y = [:]
Map x = [:]
String b = 'b'
String c = 'c'

y = y.getOrDefault( "b"    , [   "b"   : [:] ] )
     .getOrDefault( "c"    , [   "b"   : [ "c"    : []] ] ) 

x = x.getOrDefault( "${b}" , [ "${b}"  : [:] ] )
     .getOrDefault( "${c}" , [  "${b}" : [ "${c}" : []] ] )
```

However, when I try get result of `map.b.c`,

- Map `x`:

  - `x.get("${b}").get("${c}")` : works
  - `x["${b}"]["${c}"]` : `java.lang.NullPointerException`
- Map `y` works well in all various ways

```
println """
                y['b']['c'] : ${y['b']['c']} 
                      y.b.c : ${y.b.c}
        y.get('b').get('c') : ${y.get('b').get('c')}
    

              x.get("\${b}") : ${x.get("${b}")}
                  x["\${b}"] : ${x["${b}"]}                  // *why null*
  x.get("\${b}").get("\${c}") : ${x.get("${b}").get("${c}")}
"""
println """          x["\${b}"]["\${c}"]  : ${x["${b}"]["${c}"]} """
```

==> result

```
                y['b']['c'] : [] 
                      y.b.c : []
        y.get('b').get('c') : []
    
              x.get("${b}") : [c:[]]
                  x["${b}"] : null                  // *why null*
  x.get("${b}").get("${c}") : []

Exception thrown

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'c' on null object
    at ConsoleScript77.run(ConsoleScript77:21)
```

I want to know why `x.get("${b}").get("${c}")` works, but `x["${b}"]["${c}"]` got `null`

btw, here the dynamic map initialization details:

```
Map m = [
    'x' : [
        'name': 'x',
        'size': ['1', '2'],
        'age': '1',
    ],
    'y': [
        'name': 'x',
        'size': ['2', '3'],
        'age': '2'
    ]
]
Map a = [:]
m.each{ k, v ->
    v.size.each {
        String t = "${v.name}-${it}"
        a = a.getOrDefault(t, ["${t}": [:]])
        println """
            t: ${t}
            k: ${k}
            a: ${a}
            a.t: ${a.t}
            a.get("${t}"): ${a.get("${t}")}
            a["${t}"]: ${a["${t}"]}
        """
    }
}
```

=== output:

```
            t: x-1
            k: x
            a: [x-1:[:]]
            a.t: null
            a.get("x-1"): [:]
            a["x-1"]: null
        

            t: x-2
            k: x
            a: [x-2:[:]]
            a.t: null
            a.get("x-2"): [:]
            a["x-2"]: null
     ....
```

Comment: `"${b}"` - GString, `b` - String....  `assert b.hashCode() != "${b}".hashCode()`  the problem begins here.

Comment: btw - what is the question?

Comment: really appreciate @daggett ! the question is to extract the important information from `Map 1` to `Map 2 [key1][key2]`, you can check `here the dynamic map initialization details` from my question.

Comment: init map where key1 is a variable: `m = [ (key1): 123 ]`. use `x` instead of `"${x}"`. use `map[variable]` instead of `map.variable`. read more here: https://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Maps edit question and provide expected result then somebody would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate @daggett.

So the truth is:

```
y.each { k, v ->
    println """
          key: ${k} \t\t\t key.getClass(): ${k.getClass()}
        value: ${v} \t\t value.getClass(): ${v.getClass()}
    """
}

x.each { k, v ->
    println """
          key: ${k} \t\t\t key.getClass(): ${k.getClass()}
        value: ${v} \t\t value.getClass(): ${v.getClass()}
    """
}
```

==> result

```
key: b          key.getClass():   class java.lang.String
value: [c:[]]   value.getClass(): class java.util.LinkedHashMap
    

key: b          key.getClass():   class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
value: [c:[]]   value.getClass(): class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

So, according to my previous `${x["${b}"]}`, the key of x ( `"${b}"` ) was type conversion to `String`, and x only has the key belongs to `GStringImpl`, so the result is `null`

However, `.get("${b}")` works, because of :

```
println "${b}".getClass()  // class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
```

Here more details:

```
Map x = [:]
String str = 'a'

x = x.getOrDefault( "${str}", [ "${str}" : [:] ] )

x.each { k, v -> println "${k}: ${k.getClass()}" }
Map x = [:]
String str = 'a'

x = x.getOrDefault( "${str}", [ "${str}" : [:] ] )

x.each { k, v -> println "${k}: ${k.getClass()}" }     // a: class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl

assert x               == [ "${s}" : [:] ]
assert x.a             == null
assert x."${str}"      == null
assert x["${str}"]     == null
assert x[str]          == null
assert x.get(str)      == null
assert x.get("${str}") == [:]
```